# How are zone-boundary cities treated for the purpose of redemption travel?

Tags: amtrak

Take a look at [the zone map](https://www.amtrakguestrewards.com/zonemap) Amtrak provides for travel based on redemption of reward points.

[image: Amtrak zone map]

Some cities, like Wolf Point, Denver, Cincinnati, and Atlanta appear to be located on zone boundaries. Which zone do they count as? (That is, do they count "in favor" of the purchaser, so that Atlanta is in the Eastern zone for travel from DC and the Central zone for travel from New Orleans, or "against" the purchaser, so that the opposite is true?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Guidelines page](https://www.amtrakguestrewards.com/info/redemptionguidelines):

> • An Amtrak station located on a zone boundary **may be considered part of either bordering zone**, if it is the initial origin or final destination for the redemption.